# DbContextOptions UseInMemoryDatabase for .NET Core 2.2 version

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am trying write unit test for excisting .Net Core project which is build in .Net Core 2.2. 
But .Net Core 2.2 is not supporting UseInMemoryDatabase for DbContextOptions. Any Idea for workaround this?

Comment: You are most likely missing a reference. check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydbcontextoptionsextensions.useinmemorydatabase?view=efcore-3.0 and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory

Comment: @Nkosi as I mentioned it is not avaliable for .Net Core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the specific version of the package(e.g 2.2)